# Prove that for any positive integer $n$, group $S'_n$＝$A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Suppose $S_n$ is the permutation group of order n, and $A_n$ is the alternating group of order n(even permutations).

Prove that $A_n$ is the derived group of $S_n$.

Comment: It's sometimes called "the derived subgroup", but not "derivative". Also, your title is nonsensical. What "any group"?

Comment: the term derivative in maths really only applies to "continuous" functions whereas sets that you are talking about would be discrete